# React-like Portal in Flutter

Tags: flutter

In React, there is there are portals that allow a component to render at a placeholder somewhere completely else in the tree.

Is there something similar in Flutter?

Answer (score 1):

Since **December 30**, there is one lib available now:

> A flutter plugin to build a widget outside of it's current tree.
>   Similar to React Portals.

https://pub.dev/packages/portal